# My drop-down content overlaps my button, I want it to go under the navbar

Tags: css, button, hover, navbar, dropdown

My drop-down content on the navbar overlaps my button and doesnt go under the button like Id wish. The drop-down content opens at the top of my button and I want it to open at the botton of the button on the navbar. Im pretty sure the problem lies with the CSS of the navbar but I haven't figured it out yet. Any help? thank you.

```
    <ul class="nav-links">
    <li><button class="btn About"><a href="#"><b>About</b></a></button> 
    </li>
    <li><button class="btn Our Team"><a href="#"><b>Staff</b></a> 
     </button></li>
    <li><button class="btn Apps & Games"><a href="#"><b>Games</b></a> 
    </button></li>
    <li><button class="btn Contact"><a href="#"><b>Contact</b></a> 
    </button></li>
    <div class="dropdown">
    <li><button class="btn link" id="dropbtn"><a href="#"><b>Links</b> 
    </a>
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a ref="#">Link 1</a>
    <a ref="#">Link 2</a>
    <a ref="#">Link 3</a>
    <a ref="#">Link 4</a>
   </div>
   </div>

   </ul>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

li {
float: left;
font-size: 0;
}

body {
margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-image: url(.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
 }

p, p {
padding: 50px;
}  

h1 {
-webkit-text-stroke: 3px black;
font-size: 50px;
}

nav {
  height: 10vh;
  background: red;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #e60000, #e60000, #e60000,  
#e60000, black);
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-style: ridge;
  overflow: hidden;
  }



 .btn {
  border-radius: -10px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  padding: 23px 33px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.5s;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  }

 .btn:hover {
 background: black;
 }

 .nav-links {
 display: flex;
 list-style: none;
 width: 50%;
 height: 100%;
 align-items: center;
 margin-left: auto;
 }

 .nav-links li a {
 color:white;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 20px;
}

 .landing {
 height: 90vh;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 }

 .landing h1 {
  margin: 100px;
 font-size: 50px;
 color: white;
}

.dropdown {
overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
 font-size: 17px;    
 border: none;
 outline: none;
 color: white;
 padding: 14px 16px;
 background-color: inherit;
 font-family: inherit;
 margin: 0;
 float: right;
 }

.dropdown-content {
 display: none;
 list-style: none;
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #f9f9f9;
 min-width: 160px;
 box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 z-index: 1;
 }

 .dropdown-content a {
 float: none;
 color: black;
 padding: 12px 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
 text-align: left;
 }

.dropdown-content a:hover {
 background-color: #ddd;
 color: black;
 }

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
 display: block;
 }
```

Comment: maybe offsetting the `dropdown-content` with `margin-top` would work, so like: `.dropdown-content { margin-top: 20px; }`

Comment: Yes! I added margin-top: 75px and it dropped below my navbar! thank you!

Comment: no problem, happy coding :)